# why does this program output 37?

Tags: c, output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

float c = 5.0;

printf ("Temperature in Fahrenheit is %.2f", (9/5)*c + 32);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Abhiraj Das, Curious.  Why code `float c = 5.0;` instead of `double c = 5.0;`?

Comment: `9 * c / 5` would avoid the integer division.

Comment: Stack Overflow should automatically mark any question containing “Fahrenheit”, “Celsius”, ”centigrade”, or “temperature” and “9” and “5” as a suggested duplicate of one of the million others.

Answer (score 2):

Change your statement to `(9.0/5.0)*c + 32` as 9 and 5 are integers, their division returns integer that is 1. So write them in float variable format.